# Dealing with +, ++, -, -- buttons → get the next value which a button would produce anyway

Tags: vb.net

The button labeled with one plus sign and the button with one minus sign increase / decrease the value in the text box by 0.1.

The button labeled with the 2 plus signs and the button labeled with the 2 minus signs increase / decrease the value in the text box by 1.0.

The button labeled with the 3 plus signs and the button labeled with the 3 minus signs increase / decrease the value in the text box by 9.0.

**But**

If there is a crooked value in the text box, this value should jump to the next higher value that this `+`button could and would produce anyway. Example: 1007.99 becomes 1008

If there is a crooked value in the text box, this value should jump to the next higher value that this `++`button could produce. Example: 1007.99 becomes 1009

If there is a crooked value in the text box, this value should jump to the next higher value that this `+++`button could produce. Example: 1007.99 becomes 1017

A value of 1008.40 becomes 1009 with the `++`button.
A value of 1008.40 becomes 1008 with the `--`button.

The same applies to the buttons labeled with the minus sign.

*How can I get this started?*

[image: Buttons on the user interface (Form)]

==================================================

**Edit**

I've tried it with this code. The only problems I still have are the `+`button and the `-`button. It is still buggy. 1007.99—no matter how often I click—never becomes less than 1007.9 and no more than 1008.1 It seems to be an inappropiate solution to round 1007.9 to 1008 and subtract 0.1

```
Public Class FormMain
    
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
    Private Value As Double = 0R
    

    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox2.Text = "1007,99"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_3Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_3Minus.Click
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Value)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Value > 0.0 Then
            Value = Math.Round(Value, 0)
            Value -= 9.0
            TextBox2.Text = Value.ToString(Deu)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_2Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_2Minus.Click
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Value)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Value > 0.0 Then
            Value = Math.Round(Value, 0)
            Value -= 1.0
            TextBox2.Text = Value.ToString(Deu)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_1Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_1Minus.Click
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Value)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Value > 0.0 Then
            Value = Math.Round(Value, 0)
            Value -= 0.1
            TextBox2.Text = Value.ToString(Deu)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_1Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_1Plus.Click
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Value)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Value > 0.0 Then
            Value = Math.Round(Value, 0)
            Value += 0.1
            TextBox2.Text = Value.ToString(Deu)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_2Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_2Plus.Click
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Value)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Value > 0.0 Then
            Value = Math.Round(Value, 0)
            Value += 1.0
            TextBox2.Text = Value.ToString(Deu)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_3Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_3Plus.Click
        Dim erfolgreich As Boolean = Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, Value)
        If erfolgreich AndAlso Value > 0.0 Then
            Value = Math.Round(Value, 0)
            Value += 9.0
            TextBox2.Text = Value.ToString(Deu)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you post any code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to how the logic should work because I can't make sense of the rounding rules in some of your examples.

I can however offer up a alternative approach to simplify the code.  You can have the event handlers for the button presses simply call a fixed subroutine where your logic can be in one place, which is easier to edit and manage:

```
Private Sub SetValue(delta As Double)

    Dim value As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, Deu, value) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"Current value {TextBox2.Text} is invalid.")
    End If

    Dim newValue = Math.Round(value, 1) + delta
    TextBox2.Text = newValue.ToString(Deu)

End Sub


Private Sub Button_3Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_3Minus.Click
    SetValue(-9.0)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_2Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_2Minus.Click
    SetValue(-1.0)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_1Minus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_1Minus.Click
    SetValue(-0.1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_1Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_1Plus.Click
    SetValue(0.1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_2Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_2Plus.Click
    SetValue(1.0)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_3Plus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_3Plus.Click
    SetValue(9.0)
End Sub
```